# npm install with AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda

I'm writing AWS Lambda function in Javascript. 
I need to use synchronize.js library, so I ran `npm install synchronize`.
Everything works fine locally, but when I upload *.zip to AWS and run, it thorws the following error:

```
  "errorMessage": "`/var/task/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-v8-3.14/fibers.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibers`?"
```

I think it expects different binaries version installed by npm. How can I fix it?

Comment: AWS Lambda not runs `npm install` before running. any library you use you should zip too. [source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html)

Comment: I include node_modules directory in zip file. Amazon tries to find node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-v8-3.14/.. but npm installs node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-v8-4.6 folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because AWS Lambda does not execute `npm install` for you, any npm module that requires a binary build step can run into issues depending on the module's functionality, how it builds, etc. I'm not familiar with synchronize.js, but it likely needs to be built on Amazon Linux to succeed inside AWS Lambda.

So you must either:

1. Do your `npm install synchronize` on a machine running Amazon Linux, and deploy from there.
2. Replace synchronize.js with async code (callbacks, promises or async library)

In general I'd recommend #2 if at all possible. You don't actually ask a specific question so I'm not positive that would work for you, but hopefully this gives you some direction.